# Why does String.match( / \d*/ ) return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me to understand why using \d* returns an array containing an empty string, whereas using \d+ returns ["100"] (as expected). I get why the \d+ works, but don't see why exactly \d* doesn't work. Does using the * cause it to return a zero-length match, and how exactly does this work?

```
var str = 'one to 100';
var regex = /\d*/;
console.log(str.match(regex));
// [""]
```

Comment: The * character matches `zero` or more occurrences of the character in a row, the + character is similar but matches one or more.

Comment: The string is checked for a match from left-to-right. Since `\d*` can match an empty string right at index 0, it returns a match right there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that `match` is looking for the first substring it can find that matches the given regex.

`*` means that there may be zero or more of something, so `\d*` means you're looking for a string that contains zero or more digits.

If your input string started with a number, that entire number would be matched.

```
"5 to 100".match(/\d*/); // "5"
"5 to 100".match(/\d+/); // "5"
```

But since the first character is a non-digit, `match()` figures that the beginning of the string (with no characters) matches the regex.

Since your string doesn't begin with any digits, an empty string is the first substring of your input which matches that regex.

Comment: That's what PCRE does, but not POSIX regexes. POSIX always finds the longest match.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: I'm not intimately familiar with all the flavors of regex, but this is what Javascript does.

Comment: Thank you, @StriplingWarrior. I think what I find confusing is that the string (although populated), begins with an empty string. I wasn't thinking of the string "one to 100" as containing the string "". But since the regex wasn't able to find a digit at the first character, it returned the empty string "" which still qualified as a match since a "" is equal to zero or more digits. But if that qualifies as a match, does the regex engine even bother with looking at the first character and, if so, why?

Comment: @capolo2: Yes it does, because as you see from the code samples in my answer, it has to know whether it could match a larger string (still starting in the same place) by adding to that empty string at the beginning of the input.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: No, a POSIX regex would return the same result (except you would have to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`).  Different-length matches only becomes an issue when the regex employs alternation. ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#alternation))

Answer (score 4):

`/\d*/`

means "*match against 0 or more numbers starting from the beginning of the string*".

When you start the beginning for your string, it immediately hits a non-number and can't go any further. Yet this is *considered a successful match* because "0 or more".

You can try either "1 or more" via

```
/\d+/
```

or you can tell it to match "0 or more" from the end of the string:

```
/\d*$/
```

### Find all in Python

In Python, there is the `findall()` method which returns all parts of the string your regular expression matched against.

```
re.findall(r'\d*', 'one to 100')
# => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '100', '']
```

`.match()` in JavaScript, returns only the first match, which would be the first element in the above array.

Comment: Ah, making the distinction between the beginning and the end of the string helps to clear things up a bit. So the problem is that the search started from the beginning of the string, and every string starts with an empty string "", which will cause a the match of zero or more digits to succeed. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect. Thanks for the explanation, Martin.

Comment: That's exactly it. You started from the beginning and then hit a non-numeric digit, and so 0 numeric digits were "successfully" matched.

Comment: Updated with an example from Python which might clarify further.

Comment: in javascript there is the 'matchall' method

Answer (score 2):

`*` means 0 or more, so it's matching 0 times.  You need to use `+` for 1 or more.  By default it's greedy, so will match `100`:

```
var str = 'one to 100';
var regex = /\d+/;
console.log(str.match(regex));
// ["100"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @StriplingWarrior said below, the empty string is the first match, hence it is being returned. I would like to add that you can tell what the regex is matching by noticing the 'index' field which the function `match` returns. For example, this is what I get when I run your code in Chrome:

```
["", index: 0, input: "one to 100"]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rafid. I'll have to do a little more reading. I guess I don't see why it is matching the empty string, when there is a match inside of the string. Also, regarding index, why does '0' correspond to the empty string, and not to the first element in the string ('o')?

Comment: @tbutman I ask myself the same question. Did you get an answer?