# asterisk * not working with word match JavaScript \w*

Tags: javascript, regex

Am trying to extract all word character from a url to remove the leading "/"

```
"/assedede".match(/\w*/) // "" empty string
```

The above code do not match any character.
but

```
"/assedede".match(/\w+/) // "assedede"
```

why is /\w*/ not working?

Comment: `\w*` matches an empty string before `/` because `*` can match 0 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern, and `str.match(/.../)` only searches for the first match.

Comment: it is working. But since it match an empty string, then it matches the empty string before the slash. Then, it tries to gather more, but since the first character being checked is a slash, it stops here, happy to have matched an empty string.

Comment: On the contrary, the `\w+` begins its match at the `a`, then greedily take all the letters that follow

Comment: PS : I fixed the question, the match for the first is _not_ `null`,it's empty string.

Comment: Yeah, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360439/why-does-string-match-d-return-an-empty-string